# How to reference a cell into a replacement code in a recorded macro

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, replace

I'm trying to make  code that transforms a list of positions titles into standard positions predefined, an `IF` function would be too big.
The only way I thought of is to record a macro by replacing "this" for "that" and do this for all positions, but it would be a lot easier if it's possible to reference a cell instead of a text string inside the code:

```
What:="Field Installation Supervisor" (This part should be a cell reference from another sheet)
Replacement:= _ "Installation Supervisor" (This part is also a referenced cell from the same sheet as the above)
```

Don't know if it is possible to use cell reference inside this replacement code

```
Sub replacing()  

    Sheets("Active Employees June 01 2019").Select
    Cells.Replace What:="Field Installation Supervisor", Replacement:= _
        "Installation Supervisor", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

I expect to use reference cells to make update/maintenance of the file easier

Comment: Couldn't you just build a table to map one title to another and do a vlookup? No macro required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reference the cells in the normal way (and no need to select the sheet).

```
Sheets("Active Employees June 01 2019").Cells.Replace _
    What:=Sheets("this").Range("A1").Value, _
    Replacement:=Sheets("this").Range("A2").Value, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```